# Sendmail - domain listed in both relay-domains and local-host-names

Tags: sendmail

Recently took over a seemingly undocumented Sendmail 8.13.1 server, running on CentOS 4.7.

Basically need to figure out what they are trying to accomplish via the config files. One thing that I find odd is that many domains appear in both the relay-domains file as well as the local-host-names file. What might be the reason for such a configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may make some sense **without [FEATURE(relay_hosts_only)](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#relay_hosts_only)**.

`local-host-names` file (`$=w`) does not automatically catch subdomains of the listed names.
`relay-domains` file (`$=R`) **without `FEATURE(relay_hosts_only)`**automatically catches also sub-domains.

Exact domains with names listed in both files will be treated as listed in `local-host-names` but their sub-domains will be treated as listed in `relay-domains`.

Comment: It appears that FEATURE(relay_hosts_only) is not being used. It's not listed in the sendmail.mc and sendmail.cf contains "$* $=R" entries as opposed to "$=R" entries. But I don't get what you're saying - what would be the effect of the same entry in both files (outside of confusion)? It seems that it may make a difference with FEATURE(relay_hosts_only) as then the subdomains might get locally delivered instead of relayed but I'm not even sure that would happen.

Comment: **IF** example.net is present in both files **THEN*** example.net is treated as listed in local-host-names (it is a local email domain) **AND** host51.example.net is treated as listed in relay-domains ( sendmail will relay from and to it) **FI**.